# Keep container in place while scrolling the area next to it

Tags: javascript, css

I have a container (`.notes-container`) with `position: fixed;` and I would like to keep it in place while I scroll the area next to it (the rightmost area), however the container moves as I scroll. So I need `.notes-container` to be as high as `.tab-container`.

The minimal example (the HTML part) is kind of long, so I'm linking you to the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cmjyp7x1/).

Comment: have you tried using `position: sticky`

Comment: @soulshined yes, I tried `sticky`, haven't had any success though.

Comment: I'm thinking this can't be solved with pure CSS, JS has to enter the game.

Comment: it works for me, I guess I just don't understand the requirements